# Excel VBA Macro 64K Limit

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting the following error and can't figure out how to get around it: "Fixed or static data can't be larger than 64K"

I need to have a nested structure to accomplish what I need. I tried changing Currency to Single since it's a smaller data type but still nothing. I also moved the declaration of these types to a separate module to see if that would help.

Thanks!

```
Public Type ServiceLineRecord
    ServiceLineRevenue As Currency
End Type

Public Type ServiceTypeRecord
    ServiceTypeRevenue As Currency
    ServiceLines(35) As ServiceLineRecord
End Type

Public Type ProviderRecord
    ProviderRevenue As Currency
    ServiceTypes(6) As ServiceTypeRecord
End Type

Public Type LocationRecord
    LocationRevenue As Currency
    Providers(37) As ProviderRecord
End Type

Public Type PeriodRecord
    BeginDate As Date
    EndDate As Date
    TotalRevenue As Currency
    Locations(12) As LocationRecord
End Type
```

Comment: Do those need to be UDTs? Just convert them to classes.

Comment: Good point, I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: UDTs are annoyingly limited. Embrace classes, you'll never look back!